# from odoo import models, fields, api, _ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo'

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I am working in odoo v11 and try to update some python files but when I opened the files I got this error 
 from odoo import models, fields, api, _
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo'
 I haven't update anything before this message the picture may explain more

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError


class OpExamSession(models.Model):
    _name = 'op.exam.session'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _description = 'Exam Session'

    name = fields.Char(
        'Exam Session', size=256, required=True, track_visibility='onchange')
    course_id = fields.Many2one(
        'op.course', 'Course', required=True, track_visibility='onchange')
    batch_id = fields.Many2one(
        'op.batch', 'Batch', required=True, track_visibility='onchange')
    exam_code = fields.Char(
        'Exam Session Code', size=16,
        required=True, track_visibility='onchange')
    start_date = fields.Date(
        'Start Date', required=True, track_visibility='onchange')
    end_date = fields.Date(
        'End Date', required=True, track_visibility='onchange')
```

the error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/shouk1_26-11/odoo/source/odoo/addons/openeducat_exam/models/exam_session.py", line 22, in <module>
    from odoo import models, fields, api, _
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you use a virtual environment? Maybe it's deactivated?

Comment: Check all your path once again and before that check all the necessary libs are installed or not via checking requirments.txt

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an error raised due to your `odoo/addons` path not set. If the path is set then you should change the sequence in the odoo `conf` file:

```
addons_path = /odoo/addons/directory/path/addons,
              /odoo/addons/directory/path/odoo/addons
```